# How do one only submit click event (div), when using jquery live function?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

How do one only submit click event (div), when using jquery live function?

What i'm trying to do.

Click input and search for contact in mysql.
Click on contact and insert contact info to database.
This work 
The problem i'm have is that it insert all the while loop on page to msql database, i need some help fixing this.

PHP code that load when search activate:

This is in a while loop:

```
<?php 
echo '
<div id="'.$get_memID.'" class="box_content">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="left"> '.$profile_pic_lil.'&nbsp;<span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #060; ">'.$get_memfirstName.'&nbsp;'.$get_memlastName.'</span></td>
            <td width="40%"align="right" valign="top">
                <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #999999;">'.$linkUP_As.'</span>
                <input name="to_mem" type="hidden" id="to_mem" value="'.$get_mem.'" />
                <input name="to_memID" id="to_memID" type="hidden" value="'.$get_memID.'" />
                <input name="to_memfirstName" id="to_memfirstName" type="hidden" value="'.$get_memfirstName.'" />
                <input name="to_memlastName" type="hidden" value="'.$get_memlastName.'" />   
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
'; 
?>
```

Jquery Script to load search:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer;                                         
    $(".search").live('keyup',function(e){

        clearTimeout(timer);

        var ms = 200; // milliseconds
        var val = this.value;

        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            lookup(val);
        }, ms);

        var dataString = 'mysearchString='+ val;

        if(val==''){
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/happening_searchlinkUP.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#display<?php echo $id; ?>").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }

        return false; 
    });
});
```

Jquery Script to send php file to mysql:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box_content").live('click',function(e){                                    
        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("id");
        var mem_email = $("#to_mem").val();
        var mem_firstName = $("#to_memfirstName").val();
        var happening_id = $("#happening_id<?php echo $id; ?>").val();
        var info = "id=" + id + '&mem_email=' + mem_email + '&mem_firstName=' + mem_firstName + '&happening_id=' + happening_id;            

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/happening_getMem_linkUP.php",
            data: info,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#now_from_linkup<?php echo $id; ?>").html(mem_firstName);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Any help is gladly accepted, and thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you clarify? Also, some of the code formatting is awful, can you please make your code easier to read?

Comment: really not clear what your issue is

Comment: when submit form to database it insert more than once

Comment: what is the code to insert it into the DB? if bouncing isn't the issue then it's gotta be in your `/happening_getMem_linkUP.php`

Comment: @JKirchartz    code:                   if(isset($_POST['happening_id'])){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('','$login_mem','$id','$mem_id','$mem_email','$mem_firstName','$as',UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");

}

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to debounce your ajax calls, the easiest way is to do a `doOnce`

```
var doOnce = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box_content").live('click',function(e){                                    
        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("id");
        var mem_email = $("#to_mem").val();
        var mem_firstName = $("#to_memfirstName").val();
        var happening_id = $("#happening_id<?php echo $id; ?>").val();
        var info = "id=" + id + '&mem_email=' + mem_email + '&mem_firstName=' + mem_firstName + '&happening_id=' + happening_id;            
        if(doOnce){
        doOnce--;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/happening_getMem_linkUP.php",
            data: info,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#now_from_linkup<?php echo $id; ?>").html(mem_firstName);
                doOnce++;
            }
        });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

`doOnce` starts off true, so the ajax will be called and `doOnce` will be turned false disabling the ajax call, then when the ajax returns success the `doOnce` will be set back to true allowing it to run again.

You can also use [Ben Alman's Throttle & Debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)

Comment: I try your codes but i get the same result. Thanks for your help.