# How to do a doOnce function?

Tags: jquery

How to do a doOnce function?

I have this jQuery script and I want to add a doOnce function to it.
I want to click a tag and submit this function database once, but when I do it update the last updated insert not the current one.

Any help would be great.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".edit_happening").click(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var edit_id = element.attr("id");
        var edit_title = $("#edit_title<?php echo $id; ?>").val();
        var edit_start_time = $("#edit_start_time<?php echo $id; ?>").val();
        var edit_end_time = $("#edit_end_time<?php echo $id; ?>").val();
        var edit_description = $("#edit_description<?php echo $id; ?>").val();
        var edit_location = $("#edit_location<?php echo $id; ?>").val();
        var info = "edit_id=" 
            + edit_id 
            + '&edit_title=' 
            + edit_title
            + '&edit_start_time=' 
            + edit_start_time 
            + '&edit_end_time=' 
            + edit_end_time 
            + '&edit_description=' 
            + edit_description 
            + '&edit_location=' 
            + edit_location;

        if (edit_title == 'Edit Happening') {
            $("#errorMsg_edit<?php echo $id; ?>").fadeIn(200).show();
        }
        else if (edit_description == '') {
            $("#errorMsg_edit<?php echo $id; ?>").fadeOut(200).hide();
            $("#errorMsg2_edit<?php echo $id; ?>").fadeIn(200).show();
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/happening_edit.php",
                data: info,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#title<?php echo $id; ?>").html(edit_title);
                    $("#happening_edit_info<?php echo $id; ?>").fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $("#happening_info<?php echo $id; ?>").fadeIn(200).show();
                    $("#happening_msg_edit<?php echo $id; ?>").show();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#happening_msg_edit<?php echo $id; ?>").fadeOut(200).hide();
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Do you want the click event to only occur once per element with class of "edit_happening"?

Comment: yes that what i'm trying to do, and be able to do it again to a different selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *your* other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487849/how-do-one-only-submit-click-event-div-when-using-jquery-live-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more details to accurately answer, but:

http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$( '#something' ).one( function(){
   ...
} );
```